# Calculating the parameters of von Mises distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, circular-statistics, von-mises-distribution

I would like to calculate the values of the concentration ($\kappa$) and mean direction ($\mu$) for a von Mises mixture model from the theta values given by the movMF() function in R. At the bottom of this [message-chain](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2017-March/445182.html) there is a similar question with an example for a two component vonMises. The solutions seems to be $\mu = \frac{\theta}{||\theta||}$ and $\kappa = ||\theta||$, however, this gives a matrix of four values for $\mu$, where I'd expect it be only a vector of two values (one mean direction for each component). I have a feeling I misunderstood the meaning of $\mu$ or it might be that the conversion formulas are wrong. I'd appreciate any help or clarification in my matter.